# Adding AND dynamic condition in SOQL

Tags: apex, soql

Hi I am trying to add an AND condition in the below SOQL but returning me null value.

```
public static List<sobject> findRecords(String searchKey, String objectName) { 
        string recordType = 'Tegal_Ent';
        string searchText = '\'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchKey) + '%\'';  
        string query = 'SELECT Id, Name, RecordType.developerName FROM ' +objectName+ ' WHERE Name LIKE '+searchText+' AND RecordType.developerName =: '+recordType+' LIMIT 6';  
        return Database.query('SELECT Id, Name FROM ' +objectName+ ' WHERE Name LIKE '+searchText+' AND RecordType.developerName =: '+recordType+' LIMIT 6');
    }
```

Query is running into the error

```
:-Varibale dosent exist 'Tegal_Ent'
```

Comment: Queries don't return "null values", but they may be an empty list. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox - I have updated my class

Comment: I am not able put +recordType+ in Quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:` is a query binding, so the runtime expects a variable named `Tegal_Ent`, rather than the value in `recordType`. In other words, the runtime sees:

```
SELECT Id, Name, RecordType.developername FROM <<objectName>>
  WHERE Name like 'searchKey%' AND RecordType.DeveloperName = :Tegal_Ent
  LIMIT 6
```

Instead, do not use the `:` binding operator, and do enclose the string in quotes:

```
public static List<sobject> findRecords(String searchKey, String objectName) { 
        string recordType = '\'Tegal_Ent\'';
        string searchText = '\'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchKey) + '%\'';  
        string query = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM ' +objectName+ 
          ' WHERE Name LIKE '+searchText+
          ' AND RecordType.developerName = '+recordType+' LIMIT 6';  
        return Database.query(query);
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou I was trying with string.encapsulation, now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in anonymous apex: (change objectname and recordtype as per your wish)

```
String objectName = 'dummy__c';
String searchText = '%record%';
String recordType ='koli';
String query= 'SELECT Id, Name, RecordType.developerName FROM ' +objectName+ ' WHERE Name LIKE: searchText AND RecordType.developerName =:recordType LIMIT 6';
system.debug(Database.query(query));
```

output something like:

```
DEBUG|(dummy__c:{Id=a0O5h00000NkqBEEAZ, Name=record 1, RecordTypeId=0125h000000zYnHAAU}, dummy__c:{Id=a0O5h00000NkqBJEAZ, Name=record 2, RecordTypeId=0125h000000zYnHAAU})
```

Explanation:
when you use colon(:) in dynamic query with respect to a variable, make sure to use the variable inside the string quotations ('').

If you want to use a Field of an object you can go with the method described in the question

Resource:[Soql Injection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm)

Hope this helps
solution:

```
public static List<sobject> findRecords(String searchKey, String objectName) { 
        string recordType = 'Tegal_Ent';
        string searchText = '%'+searchKey+'%';  
        string query = 'SELECT Id, Name, RecordType.developerName FROM ' +objectName+ ' WHERE Name LIKE '+searchText+' AND RecordType.developerName =: '+recordType+' LIMIT 6';  
        return Database.query('SELECT Id, Name FROM ' +objectName+ ' WHERE Name LIKE: searchText AND RecordType.developerName =: recordType LIMIT 6');
}
```